# javascript array mapping by one attribut

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array

```
Array(4)
0: {Username: "admin", Enabled: true, ...}
1: {Username: "ftyjfj", Enabled: true, ...}
2: {Username: "ghjfgj", Enabled: true, ...}
3: {Username: "foo", Enabled: true, ...}


Array(4)
0: User {username: "foo", email: "foo@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: false}
1: User {username: "admin", email: "admin@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: false}
2: User {username: "sgrillon", email: "sgrillon@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: false}
3: User {username: "toto", email: "toto@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: false}
```

I want change `isAdmin` attribut from 2nd array **if** `username` is present in 1st array (on `Username` attribut).

So: `isAdmin: true` for foo and admin:

```
Array(4)
0: User {username: "foo", email: "foo@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: true}
1: User {username: "admin", email: "admin@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: true}
2: User {username: "sgrillon", email: "sgrillon@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: false}
3: User {username: "toto", email: "toto@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: false}
```

Comment: Aaaand your question/problem you're stuck on implementing this is…?

Comment: I try with `.map` and `.find` ...

Comment: i see no .map nor .find on the question... paste them here!

Comment: Try using Array.prototype.includes()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Create an array of names: `const names = firstArray.map(item=>item.Username);` Use that to map over second array: `second.map(item=>({...item, isAdmin:names.includes(item.username)}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a working live demo with [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach) & [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), see code below :

```js
var a = [{
  Username: "admin"
}, {
  Username: "ftyjfj"
}, {
  Username: "ghjfgj"
}, {
  Username: "foo"
}]
var b = [{
  username: "foo",
  email: "foo@foo.com",
  enabled: true,
  status: "CONFIRMED",
  isAdmin: false
}, {
  username: "admin",
  email: "admin@foo.com",
  enabled: true,
  status: "CONFIRMED",
  isAdmin: false
}, {
  username: "sgrillon",
  email: "sgrillon@foo.com",
  enabled: true,
  status: "CONFIRMED",
  isAdmin: false
}, {
  username: "toto",
  email: "toto@foo.com",
  enabled: true,
  status: "CONFIRMED",
  isAdmin: false
}]

b.forEach(obj => {
  if (a.some(val => val.Username === obj.username)) {
    obj.isAdmin = true;
  }
  return obj;
})

console.log(b)
```

Comment: Why using `map` for a simple iteration?

Comment: Because I created an external array, but it's not necessar. I removed hem. Thanks

Comment: And why use `.filter` instead of `.some` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms Because I forget it ! Thanks too

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combination of a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) + [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Here is a solution:

```
const next = users.map(user =>
  Object.assign({}, user, {
    isAdmin: data.some(d => d.Username === user.username),
  })
);
```

Comment: This is the only answer using `map` properly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all to simplify checking for existence in the first array, let's make it a map:

```
let mappedUsers = firstArray.reduce((m, el) => { m[el.username] = el; return m; }, {});
```

Then we can easily update your second array by simply checking if username exists as a key in our map:

```
secondArray.map(el => { if (el.username in mappedUsers) { el.isAdmin = true; } return el; });
```

Or we can just run through each element using `forEach` and update it accordingly:

```
secondArray.forEach(el => { if (el.username in mappedUsers) { el.isAdmin = true; } });
```

Comment: The initial `reduce` value which is `[]` should be `{}`. There is also no valid reason to use `map` for a simple iteration.

Comment: @plalx thanks, I've changed the initial value. There is a valid reason which is time. Looking up for a key is constant in time but iterating every time searching for a value is not.

Comment: I'm referring to `secondArray.map`, not the construction of the lookup structure which is more efficient in theory: `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`, but may not be faster in practice depending on the size of the inputs.

Comment: Ahh, ok. So using a map is declarative and should be read as "I'm mapping (changing) the values of the array", using a loop is like "for every value of the array do something". The second one is imperative and requires more reading from the developer to figure out intention of the author.

Comment: Actually you are wrong with your assumptions. `map` assumes a new array is returned and that no mutation occurs, it's a pure functional concept. You are conflating both ideas here, using `map`, but then mutating the array entries. @Samual Vaillant does a good use of `map`, while yours should be `forEach`.

Comment: I don't think I violated any map rule here. New array is created but with the same elements as the previous one. Of course there is mutation on some elements but the old array is not touched. Notice that we can modify elements using map even in haskell, e.g. if the elements are of type `IORef`. Using `map` tells much more what is being done here than `forEach`.

Comment: Well, the OP never specified he needed another array in the first place and I see no reason to generate a new one if the goal was to mutate the data in the original one. The `map` usage is extremely misleading here IMO, but I guess we will have to agree to disagree ;)

Comment: @plalx I've updated my answer and included also solution using `forEach`. We don't need to argue about it :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem could be first creating a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from the `usernames` of the first array. Then you can loop over the second array and if the `username` is present on the mentioned `Set`, we change the `isAdmin` property to `true`.

```js
var arr1 = [
  {username: "admin", enabled: true},
  {username: "ftyjfj", enabled: true},
  {username: "ghjfgj", enabled: true},
  {username: "foo", enabled: true}
];

var arr2 = [
  {username: "foo", email: "foo@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: false},
  {username: "admin", email: "admin@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: false},
  {username: "sgrillon", email: "sgrillon@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: false},
  {username: "toto", email: "toto@foo.com", enabled: true, status: "CONFIRMED", isAdmin: false}
];

let adminSet = new Set(arr1.map(o => o.username));
arr2.forEach(x => adminSet.has(x.username) && (x.isAdmin = true));
console.log(arr2);
```